# Import info from Word 2013 form into Access 2013 via VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I’m trying to make VBA script for Access 2013 which will help to process Word 2013 forms from folder, attach these files of Word 2013 form to relevant record entry and attach pdf file from same folder with the same name.
Since I’m not a programmer each try leads me to next error.
Can anyone help to make it work.
Thanks.

This code does task of collecting data from files .docx in folder.
Then not to keep files in folder I would like to save them in DB by the proper record.
How to add code that will attach pdf and docx file to the relevant record, assuming that filename of docx and pdf is the same?
I need a clue how to incert it to relevant record or start new part of script. what commands can be used and in what place to start new part of script?

```
Private Sub ImportFormdata_Click()
  Dim appWord As Word.Application
  Dim doc As Word.Document
  Dim SourceFolderPath As String
  Dim FormFile As String
  Dim strName As String
  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

  SourceFolderPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\"
  FormFile = Dir(SourceFolderPath & "*.docx", vbNormal)

  Do While FormFile <> ""
  Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  strName = SourceFolderPath & FormFile
  Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open(strName)
  appWord.Visible = False
  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("FormData")
  With rst
     .AddNew
     ![Question1] = doc.FormFields("Q1").result
     ![Question2] = doc.FormFields("Q2").result
     ![Question3] = doc.FormFields("Q3").result
     ![File name] = FormFile
     .Update
     .Close
  End With
  doc.Close
  appWord.Quit
  FormFile = Dir
  Loop

MsgBox "Forms imported!"
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI - `“\*.docx”` is not the same as `"\*.docx"` - do not try to use smart-quotes to replace double-quotes or you will get some **very** strange problems.

Comment: thanks. did not notice difference and could not understand why it stops at this line